# Orchard CMS custom field admin settings

Tags: orchardcms

I have a custom field in Orchard, I want it to have its own admin view to set the fields default value so that when it is used with other parts - it will always use this default display value.

I have the part, and the admin menu, currently the admin menu goes to the fields settings controller, but how do I create the fields shape for display?

I imagine something like this, but can't figure out what is the correct way to create the fields editor shape:

```
[Admin]
public class FieldAdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult TimezoneSettings()
    {
       // var timezoneShape = Shape.Create("?");
       // var model = new TimezoneViewModel(timezoneShape);
       // return View(model);

       // Or:

       // TimezonePart part = Services.ContentManager.New<ITimezoneField>("TimezoneField");
       //var model = Services.ContentManager.BuildEditor(part);
       // return View(model);
    }
}
```

The field does already work (i.e. the driver is working) when you attach the field to a content part via the admin UI, but I will only be using it with other code created custom parts in my modules.

Comment: I think you would want something like [this](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings/). This is the way to add site settings, without writing a whole screen yourself

Comment: I'll have a go at that approach...then see what happens.